# Converting list of pairwise comparisons to hierarchical representation (columns) using pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures, pairwise

I have a data set of the following form (around 8000 rows)

```
Employee ID | Manager ID
a | b
c | b
b | e
d | e
e | f
```

I will like to convert this into a form, where the entire 'link' between an employee at the lowest hierarchical level and the all managers at the 'top' hierarchical level are showed, i.e.:

```
Employee ID | Manager ID 1 | Manager ID 2 | Manager ID 3
a | b | e | f
c | b | e | f
d | e | f
```

What is the most efficient way to compute this using `pandas` in Python?

Answer (score 2):

This relates more to graph and tree theory. Pandas doesn't specialize in this field. For this kind of matter, networkx is more appropriate. I propose a solution using networkx. You need install or `pip` [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/install.html) before processing.

Construct a `DiGraph` from your dataframe. Get list of `leaves` of the graph. Use list comprehension with `shortest_path` to get lists of nodes from each `root` to `leaf`

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Employee ID', 'Manager ID', create_using=nx.DiGraph)
leaves = [node for node in G if G.out_degree(node)==0]
data   = [nx.shortest_path(G, node, leaf) for node in G if G.in_degree(node)==0 
                                               for leaf in leaves]
manager_cols = [f'Manager ID {i}' for i in range(1, df['Manager ID'].nunique()+1)]

df_final = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Employee ID', *manager_cols])

Out[371]:
  Employee ID Manager ID 1 Manager ID 2 Manager ID 3
0           a            b            e            f
1           c            b            e            f
2           d            e            f         None
```

Comment: Great answer. But assuming there are 2 line managers (i.e. more than a single shortest path) how could both variants be returned as separate rows in the final output?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `numpy` not with `pandas` but maybe it helps you nevertheless:

```py
employee = np.array(['a', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f'])  # Add 'f' as employee 
manager = np.array(['b', 'b', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f'])   # being his own manager
```

Get the number of the manger ([sorry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzO9W.jpg)) for each employee:

```py
manager_idx = np.array([np.where(employee == mng)[0] for mng in manager]).ravel()
```

Loop till you are at the end of the hierarchy

```py
manager_idx_list = [manager_idx]
while True:
    new_manger_idx = manager_idx_list[-1][manager_idx]
    if all(new_manger_idx == manager_idx_list[-1]):
        break
    else:
        manager_idx_list.append(new_manger_idx)


manager_list = np.array([employee[mng_idx] for mng_idx in manager_idx_list]).T
# 'a': [['b' 'e' 'f']
# 'c':  ['b' 'e' 'f']
# 'b':  ['e' 'f' 'f']
# 'd':  ['e' 'f' 'f']
# 'e':  ['f' 'f' 'f']
# 'f':  ['f' 'f' 'f']]
```